# Reading defined Data from SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a Problem with reading data with Pandas.read_sql (...):

My code Looks like this:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas as pd

con = pg.connect(host='db123', database='data', user='ortm', password='***')

db = pd.read_sql_query('select calculationtime, state from stateresult WHERE ID = A123', con)
```

I get the following Error Message:
Execution failed on sql 'select calculationtime, state from stateresult WHERE ID = A123': FEHLER:  Spalte â€žg351â€œ existiert nicht
LINE 1: ...m stateresult WHERE ID = A123

I tried this with another column which is a boolean or integer. I think it has sth. to do with the column being defined as character varying(250).
I tried to get it to work with a CAST but that didnt work neither.
[I'm using Python 2.7]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this once and inform the response you got.
If your connection with database is correct.But I am not aware about python.Once check it and revert to me if it gives error message.

```
   db = pd.read_sql_query("select calculationtime, state from stateresult WHERE ID = 'A123'", con)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it now. You have to pass the Information (ID='A123') as a set of Parameters by using 'params'=...